# Why numpy 1.14 rounds float16 65504 to 65500

Tags: python, numpy

I run the following code with numpy 1.14.2 on Windows

```
print(np.array(65504, dtype=np.float16))
```

I get the result `65500.0`.

But I run the `finfo(np.float16)` I get the following output:

```
Machine parameters for float16
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =   3   resolution = 1.00040e-03
machep =    -10   eps =        9.76562e-04
negep =     -11   epsneg =     4.88281e-04
minexp =    -14   tiny =       6.10352e-05
maxexp =     16   max =        6.55040e+04
nexp =        5   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

It shows the max is 65504. And I run the same code with numpy 1.13, it prints 65504.0.

What am I missing with numpy 1.14?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In NumPy 1.14, the floating-point stringification algorithm [has been changed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/release.html#many-changes-to-array-printing-disableable-with-the-new-legacy-printing-mode) to print the shortest representation that still rounds to the original value, like regular Python floats.

"Shortest" here is in terms of significant figures, so 65500.0 is considered shorter than 65504.0. Since `np.float16('65500.0')` produces the same value, `65500.0` is the representation that gets printed.

Comment: Can you add a line on what it was originally?

Comment: @kabanus: I'm not sure what it was before. Probably something like "stringify to some fixed number of digits and suppress trailing 0s when that results in output like `123.400`".

Comment: @Joe: No. I'm not sure where you're seeing such a statement in the docs. Maybe you're misreading the "This will usually shorten float16 fractional output, and sometimes float32 and float128 output." part and thinking that those are the only effects of the changed algorithm.

Comment: Ok, comment deleted :)